# Are there any negative effects of asking many questions that get no answers at all?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

**Disclaimer**: I did try to search for an existing question on meta but have not found one.

---

I am planning on asking a series of questions on Stack Exchange platform, more specifically -- on Code Review.SE. The questions are going to be about implementations of the common algorithms that are described in numerous books and online sources. Due to the nature of the questions, I anticipate that many of them will get zero responses. **I wonder whether it may result in any negative effects on my account**. (Similarly to how users are getting disallowed to ask questions if they delete too many of their previously asked questions).

I assume that the policy is universal to all Stack Exchange sites, and is not specific to Code Review, nor Stack Overflow, nor any other.

Comment: "What matters are *poorly-received* posts. That is, questions that are downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way. These can all result in post bans..." ([Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601))

Comment: @gnat I was hoping that is the case, but at the sake time was worried that questions without any responses are punished too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are merely suffering from lack of attention, then nothing bad will happen. We have the Tumbleweed badge to emphasize this.

Just make sure that they're on-topic and not likely to be downvoted and you should be fine.

I also usually prefer to space out groups of questions to one question each UTC day so that they can all count towards the asking days badges, and to avoid running into ratelimits.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it is ok by the sites rules to have a lot of zero-vote non-answered question as Stephen Leppik's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358338/477420) says.

In reality asking *a lot* of similarly structured questions in relatively short amount of time (as well as any other "bulk edit"-looking action) will likely cause at very least long discussions on corresponding meta sites at best and some serious negative backlash in worse cases. Clear explanation of the mission (like "creating canonical answers for ..." or "show/solve common problems caused by...") may help, discussing on meta would be advisable.

If you would post such "is my implementation of an algorithm look good" questions on SO they likely be off-topic as duplicates or too broad/opinion based and collect close votes (possibly coupled with downvotes unless you demonstrate why standard solutions not working in your practical scenario).

You possibly could make some part of such questions on-topic on SO if you have concerns about particular implementations/particular parts of the code. You would need to also show what existing articles/questions you already checked about each algorithm.

Note that in addition to https://codereview.stackexchange.com you may want to consider https://cs.stackexchange.com/ - if your question is more on theoretical side. In either case make sure to ask on corresponding meta site before asking wave of similar questions.